# Not able to install homebrew on my m1 macbook

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I am trying to install homebrew on m1 MacBook but I am getting this error message every time when I try to run this command.
Please anyone help me to fix this.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

**How to install HomeBrew on new MacBook: macOS Big Sur**

install HomeBrew from terminal [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

- `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

### After installation, we need to change path

Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
==> Installation successful!

**To change path**, follow **Next steps:** - Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/username/.zprofile **As mentioned in terminal**:

- `echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/username/.zprofile`
- `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

**All done** ready to use brew, check HomeBrew version:

```
brew --version
```

**Output**

```
Homebrew 3.1.5
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 5741ae3fec; last commit 2021-05-08)
```

Comment: If I do your advice: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)", it fails with: dyld[76961]: symbol not found in flat namespace '_BrotliDecoderCreateInstance'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to figure this out after being pointed in the right direction.  Full details can be found here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/100633

In summary, my ISPs (Virgin Media) Web Safe Settings were on, and this resulted in some issue with connecting to github (ping GitHub.com via terminal and search the IP to see where its pointing to), so had to turn off the web settings, rebooted my router just in case and used a new terminal window to ping github.com again and noticed a change in the IP address.  Tried reinstalling Homebrew again and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i fix the problem open the terminal as rosseta.

1. finder - application - utility - terminal - right mouse button - 'bring the imformation (i'm not sure, i'm korean user)' - check the 'open with the rosseta' - and try install homebrew again ! !

Answer (score 0):

(copy-paste Homebrew with the terminal)
and...
==> Installation successful!

But, you will get a warning " /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH". Then, follow the Next steps guide showed in terminal to finish add Homebrew to your PATH.

To end, type "brew -v" to check installed brew version.